# BUG with Generating an Integer Grid in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I encountered a problem with generating a grid of integers in Python. My code:

```
c = [[0] * 3] * 3
print c

c[0][0] = 1
print c
```

The first `print` statement prints as follows, which is the grid I want

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

The second `print` statement prints as follows, which is *not* what I want. I just wanted to change `grid[0][0]` to 1, but not every head of the lists in grid.

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

How do I generate a grid in a quick way, without this kind of modification issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append(0)
b = []
for i in range(3):
    b.append(a[:])

print b
b[0][0] = 1
print b.  This code performs well, but it is too tedious.

Comment: `c = [[0]*3 for _ in xrange(3)]` - see duplicate for explanation.